# how to get next month with the date +1 from today php

Tags: php, date

for e.g. date is 21/01/2015
I want to get 22/02/2015(next month with the increment in date from 21 to 22)

how cam I achieve that?
I am using  strtotime('+1  month'); **output**:- 21/02/2015.. and this will only gives me next month with present date i.e 21

Comment: What do you expect to get on 30th January?

Comment: `strtotime('-1 month');` and you get `21/02/2015` ? Where is the logic?!

Comment: Note that to get ___next___ month, you would normally do `+1 month`, not `-1 month`

Comment: I am sorry i am using strtotime('+1 month');  typing mistake.. and i have edited it

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess

```
strtotime('-1 day', strtotime('-1 month'))
```

Or, if you actually need the next month, not the previous one, then

```
strtotime('+1 day', strtotime('+1 month'))
```

It will have interesting artifacts if the corresponding day does not exist (like if you call it on January, 31st), but I guess it is not clear what to do in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try below :-

```
$end_date = mktime(0,0,0,date('m')+1,date('d')+1,date('Y'));

echo date('Y-m-d', $end_date);
```

Answer (score -2):

i will send you

```
$day = date('d');
$month = date('m')+1;
$year = date('Y');
$nextDay = $day+1;
$nextMonth = $month + 1; 
echo $nextDate = $nextDay.'/'.$nextMonth.'/'.$year;
```

Comment: It's a Q&A site, not  a forum, please avoid things like "Hello" and "Thanks" if it's not helpfull for the answer. Read the guidelines to learn how to improve your answer and use text formating to clarify your post not to make it more visible

Comment: What happens on December 31st? nextMonth is `13` and nextDay is `32`?